# How to find the number of days between two different dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have basic query:

```
SELECT A.Username
    ,EH.[From]
    ,EH.[End]
    ,DATEDIFF(d, [From], [End]) AS HolidaysInDays
FROM EmployeHoliday EH
LEFT JOIN Admin A ON EH.UserId = A.AdminId
WHERE EH.IsActive = 1
```

If employee apply leave(LeaveStart = "17 Dec 2019" to LeaveEnd = "19 Dec 2019"),
when I execute my query the output is HolidaysInDays = 2 but the actual Days is 3. So, how can I resolve this problem?

My output is as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: You are asking us how to add one?

Comment: Your underlying data is exactly 2 days anyway when time parts are considered. Can people take a half day off? If so how is that represented in `EmployeHoliday`?

Answer (score 1):

When using `DATEDIFF`, the end date is an *exclusive* date so is not factored into the calculation:

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(d, '2019-12-17', '2019-12-19')
```

Output:

```
2
```

To add the final date in, just add 1 to the result:

```
PRINT DATEDIFF(d, '2019-12-17', '2019-12-17') + 1
PRINT DATEDIFF(d, '2019-12-17', '2019-12-18') + 1
PRINT DATEDIFF(d, '2019-12-17', '2019-12-19') + 1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:
what is 7 - 5?

Boom.